# Postgres Proper Index for Sorting and Join

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple schema and query, but am experiencing consistent awful performance with certain parameters.

**Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  barcode_id integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE barcodes (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  value citext NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY locations ADD CONSTRAINT locations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY barcodes ADD CONSTRAINT barcodes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY locations ADD CONSTRAINT fk_locations_barcodes FOREIGN KEY (barcode_id) REFERENCES barcodes(id);

CREATE INDEX index_barcodes_on_value ON barcodes (value);
CREATE INDEX index_locations_on_barcode_id ON locations (barcode_id);
```

**Query**:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM locations
JOIN barcodes ON locations.barcode_id = barcodes.id
ORDER BY barcodes.value ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

**Analysis**:

```
Limit  (cost=0.71..3564.01 rows=50 width=34) (actual time=0.043..683.025 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..4090955.00 rows=57404 width=34) (actual time=0.043..683.017 rows=50 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using index_barcodes_on_value on barcodes  (cost=0.42..26865.99 rows=496422 width=15) (actual time=0.023..218.775 rows=372138 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using index_locations_on_barcode_id on locations  (cost=0.29..5.32 rows=287 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=372138)
              Index Cond: (barcode_id = barcodes.id)
Planning time: 0.167 ms
Execution time: 683.078 ms
```

500+ ms for the number of entries in my schema (500,000 barcodes and 60,000 locations) doesn't make sense. Can I do anything to improve the performance?

*Note:*

Even stranger is the execution time depends on the data. In drafting this question I attempted to include seeded random data, but the seeds seem to be performant:

**Seed:**

```
INSERT INTO barcodes (id, value) SELECT seed.id, gen_random_uuid() FROM generate_series(1,500000) AS seed(id);
INSERT INTO locations (id, barcode_id) SELECT seed.id, (RANDOM() * 500000)  FROM generate_series(1,60000) AS seed(id);
```

**Analysis:**

```
Limit  (cost=0.71..3602.63 rows=50 width=86) (actual time=0.089..1.123 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..4330662.42 rows=60116 width=86) (actual time=0.088..1.115 rows=50 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using index_barcodes_on_value on barcodes  (cost=0.42..44972.42 rows=500000 width=41) (actual time=0.006..0.319 rows=376 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using index_locations_on_barcode_id on locations  (cost=0.29..5.56 rows=301 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=376)
              Index Cond: (barcode_id = barcodes.id)
Planning time: 0.213 ms
Execution time: 1.152 ms
```

**Edit**:

Analysis of the tables:

```
ANALYZE VERBOSE barcodes;
INFO:  analyzing "public.barcodes"
INFO:  "barcodes": scanned 2760 of 2760 pages, containing 496157 live 
rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 496157 estimated total rows
ANALYZE
Time: 62.937 ms

ANALYZE VERBOSE locations;
INFO:  analyzing "public.locations"
INFO:  "locations": scanned 254 of 254 pages, containing 57394 live rows 
and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 57394 estimated total rows
ANALYZE
Time: 21.447 ms
```

Comment: cluster both tables by barcode_id

Comment: @Jasen reading up on 'cluster' - I've never used. I tried running: `CLUSTER barcodes USING barcodes_pkey;` and `CLUSTER locations USING index_locations_on_barcode_id;` but it didn't seem to help. Should I be using it differently?

Comment: @Jasen also - it sounds like 'cluster' isn't a permanent command - but might require re-runs?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328)

Comment: Stupid question: did you run `ANALYZE` on both tables before you ran your query?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I didn't, but now have and pasted in the question.

Comment: If you execute the same queries, with the same values, several times in quick succession, do the timings get faster? If this is the case, then what slows you down is random IO wait, which is then cached in the subsequent executions, and the solution might well be a covering index. Yout 500ms time supports IO wait, since that would make 50 accesses (your LIMIT) at 10ms each.

Comment: @peufeu multiple executions didn't make a difference (same performance time).

Comment: Interesting. Does this query have the same timing problems ? ==> SELECT * FROM barcodes ORDER BY barcodes.value ASC
LIMIT 50;

Comment: ...And then, try this: "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE barcode_id IN (list of ids returned from previous query);" Try to find which table slows it down, and if you can find a set of ids that is slow, and one that is fast. Shooting a bit in the dark here...

Comment: @peufeu no - the non-joined queries are both sub ms queries.

Comment: The plot thickens... How about: "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE barcode_id IN (SELECT * FROM barcodes ORDER BY barcodes.value ASC LIMIT 50);" which should have the same result as previous query... You could also use "WITH aa AS (SELECT * FROM barcodes ORDER BY barcodes.value ASC LIMIT 50) SELECT * FROM locations
JOIN aa ON locations.barcode_id = aa.id" whose EXPLAIN ANALYZE should give you separate timings for each... Very weird... Maybe citext has hidden slowdowns?

Comment: @peufeu the above query is different (barcode and location is not a one to one mapping - will return < 50 results) - and it is performant (after switching to select only the id for the subselect).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139412/discussion-between-peufeu-and-stussa).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `barcodes` with low values don't have matches in `locations`, which PostgreSQL cannot know. So its plan to fetch the `barcodes` in the correct output order via the index and then join values from `locations` until it found 50 of them is much worse than it expected.

I would `ANALYZE` the tables and

```
DROP INDEX index_barcodes_on_value;
```

That should keep PostgreSQL from choosing that plan.

I don't know what plan PostgreSQL will choose then.
For a nested loop the following index *might* help:

```
CREATE INDEX ON locations(id);
```

Comment: Hehe, that was exactly what I was about to reply, so I'm upvoting. Optimizing this is going to be tricky, as removing the index will need a huge, slow sort, unless the number of matching rows in both tables is very small. Materializing the "value" column in "locations" table, along with an index, would make the query very fast, but it denormalizes and fattens the table, so it should only be considered if this is a very important query.